# Using the onclick method to grab $this row and populate a web form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to select data from a table row and use that very data in a web form. I've been able to pass the record id as a data-attribute of the row. I am stuck on the part where I have to use the $.on() function and also what do I put in the PHP Webform that will be associated with this Javascript code?

Thanks

### Here is the Javascript

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function() {

        //Get the ID from the row clicked
        var id = $(this).data('recordId'); 

        //short-hand
        $('#section2').load('data_entry_form.php?id='+id);

});
```

### Here is the PHP for the Web Form (see the first few lines where I try to "catch" the record id that was selected by the user.

```
<html>
<form>
<?php
   $_GET['id'];

   echo $id; //should echo the id being sent across.
?>
<input type="date"></input><br>
<input list="auditors" placeholder="Auditor" />
<datalist id="auditors">
    <option value="Foo" />
</datalist><br>
<input list="city" placeholder="City" />
<datalist id="city">    
    <option value="Bar" />
</datalist><br>
<input type="submit" name="submitbutton" id="submitbutton" value="Submit" />
</form>
</html>
```

### Here is the PHP that generated the original table that I selected the rows from. Here I have passed a data-attribute which is the "fee_source_id" (identical to the first column in the table).

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$result = $dbh->query("
    SELECT a_aif.aif_id,
      a_aif.fee_source_id,
      a_aif.company_name_per_sedar,
      a_aif.document_filing_date,
      IF (a_aif_remaining.aif_id IS NULL, 0, 1) `match`
    FROM  a_aif
      LEFT JOIN a_aif_remaining
        ON a_aif_remaining.aif_id = a_aif.aif_id
    WHERE aif_id = {$id}
    ORDER BY aif_id DESC");

$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ( !empty($result) ) : endif;

?>

<table = "all_aifs">
<tr>
    <th><b>Document ID</b></th>
    <th><b>Pubco Name</b></th>
    <th><b>Filing Date</b></th>
    <th><b>PDF</b></th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($result as $index => $row) : ?>
<tr data-recordId="<?=$row[fee_source_id];?>"
    class="<?=$row["match"] ? "match" : "";?>">
    <td><?php echo $row[fee_source_id]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[company_name_per_sedar]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[document_filing_date]; ?></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<? endforeach;?>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where is '$row['aif_id']' set at?  In the code above, you have '$id' and $row['aif_id'] but where is that $row['aif_id'] being set?  Is $row supposed to represent the data loaded with $id?

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('table').find('tr').on({
     click: (function(e){
        var id = $(this).data('recordId');
        $('#section2').load('data_entry_form.php?id='+id);

     })

    });

});


<?php
   $id = $_GET['id'];

   echo $id; //should echo the id being sent across.
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, Schenn. I think what you have written makes sense to me. The aif_id was being set in the table row html element, i will update the question to include that fact.

Comment: upon review I meant to have "fee_source_id" instead of "aif_id" but neither of which I think I should have... looks like I need "id"

Comment: After looking at the updated code... Where is the "Where aid_id = '$id'" clause?  Or do you load the table and then try to access the specific row of the return via the $id.

In other words:  Do you load the table, then get the requested ID from the click event, compare that requested ID to the loaded table data and generate the form from that data.  Or do you take the ID, select the row from the table using the ID to limit your search to just the row you are after and then use THAT data to generate the form?

Comment: I am trying to access the specific record in the database and it's related fields from the $id. I've just done all that you said and find the result "undefined".

Comment: So in your SQL query, after FROM `a_aif`, you need to add "WHERE `aid_id` = {$id}"  Also, the field names and table names need to have a ` (next to 1 in the num row) character around them.


for fun, open up your phpMyAdmin, copy that sql statement (change the recommended WHERE aif_id = {$id}" to "WHERE aif_id = an id value that you know exists in the table" into the sql box and see what it returns.

Comment: please see the updated question, I've made a lot of updates for you to see and make it more clear.

Comment: Yea, without the WHERE clause, sql doesnt know what ID to load.  You got the real important bit, the ID is coming across successfully.  

try:
    <?php

     $id = $_GET('id');
     $dbh = (stuff you already have)
     $dbh->query("
          SELECT a_aif.aif_id,
      a_aif.fee_source_id,
      a_aif.company_name_per_sedar,
      a_aif.document_filing_date
    FROM  a_aif 
      LEFT JOIN a_aif_remaining
        ON a_aif_remaining.aif_id = a_aif.aif_id
    WHERE a_aif.aif_id = {$id}
    ORDER BY aif_id DESC" 
     ");

Comment: oops, thats $id = $_GET['id'] not $_GET('id')

Comment: I get this error now "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '} ORDER BY aif_id DESC' at line 9' in /home/theaudit/public_html/_sandbox/all_aifs.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /home/theaudit/public_html/_sandbox/all_aifs.php(19): PDO->query('?? SELECT a_...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/theaudit/public_html/_sandbox/all_aifs.php on line 19"

Comment: I updated the $_GET and included the where clause - see updates above too.

Comment: In the updated code, $id is no longer being set to $_GET['id'].  ($id = $_GET['id'])  Now, in the code above, you are taking the id from the request, but where do you use that ID to generate the result?

In your "generate the whole table" function, you do not need a where clause.  That generates the table, you want the all data and rows.

In the "gets the information" bit, all you have at the time of the request is the $_GET['id'] variable.  The list of data that was generated when the table was created no longer exists. So you need to take that id and put it into another select query.

Comment: But that's why echo $id is displaying "undefined".

After getting echo $id to spit out the id number you are sending across, you will have to write another query to get the data you need using that ID as a limiter to your query.

pdo->query works better when you don't have a limiter and are just running a basic sql statement.  When doing a search for id, you are better off using whats called a prepared statement.

After the $id = $_GET['id'] line.  Write the following:

Comment: $sql = "SELECT a_aif.aif_id,
      a_aif.fee_source_id,
      a_aif.company_name_per_sedar,
      a_aif.document_filing_date
    FROM  a_aif
      LEFT JOIN a_aif_remaining
        ON a_aif_remaining.aif_id = a_aif.aif_id
    WHERE a_aif.aif_id = :idToFind
    ORDER BY aif_id DESC";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([:idToFind =>$id]);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

now your row should be equal to the row in your database with that $id value.

Comment: Some information to help understand whats happening.

$_GET is whats called a super global in PHP.  It represents an associative array of the keys and values that are sent across during a GET request. For example.  www.example.com/?id=2&foo=bar would create a $_GET array that would look like
['id'=>2,'foo'=>'bar'].  You want to take your value out of it and assign it to ID so that you aren't messing with that array but with only the values you need.

Comment: never seen this syntax before [:idToFind =>$id

Comment: So I need another sql query in the data_entry_form.php?

Comment: thanks very much for your help to explain this. appreciate it!

Comment: ['key'=>value] is called an associative array.

I would recommend spending some time going over learning some of the key PHP systems.  Associative arrays and PDO are very important things to know while working with PHP.  Try playing around with something simpler then what you've got going on there... and head through some tutorials on php, mysql and html forms.  

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

and 

https://phpacademy.org/

Comment: I think I've just understood the biggest problem with all of this. I don't have the xmlHTTPRequest sending the data that was selected by clicking on the row to the server.

Comment: the xmlHTTPRequest is handled automatically by jquery and php.  All you will (need to) see on the php side is the $_GET or $_POST which php pulls from the xmlHTTPRequest object.  In firebug, (make sure its active for the page your testing on), open up the Console window and then click on the table row in your browser.  You should see an entry in the console such as GET url or POST url.
If you click on that entry, you will see the xmlHTTPRequest object under the "headers" tab.
$.load() is a GET request by default, unless you also send across a data object in which case it becomes a POST request

Comment: greate tutorials above, thanks! and yes, you are absolutely right, I can see that there is an AJAX request sent... OK so the xmlHTTPRequest isn't the problem after all...

Comment: I've uploaded a picture of what I see now. Almost there with your code, just missing something, and I have NO idea what that is...

Comment: So it's now outputting your php code to the page? Check your opening and closing php tags and make sure that the lines in that picture above are inside a php tag.